# mysql (5.1) insert syntax > col_name=value?

Tags: mysql, syntax, insert

Is there a way in mysql to insert a *new* row in a way that more directly associates a value with its column (rather than `table(col_name) values(value)`)? When inserting a lot of values at one time, listing them in-line gets rather confusing and leads to errors/mistakes.

I'm looking for something more like `UPDATE`'s syntax of `SET col_name='value'`.

I see in the [mysql doc for INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) there is the following:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT}, ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

but that is just for duplicates :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the MySQL docs, `[text]` means "`text` is optional". So this is perfectly valid:

```
INSERT INTO table
SET col1='value1', col2='value2'...
```