# You have an error in your SQL syntax Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My sql query is :

```
"INSERT INTO
    order customer_id = $customer_id
    , firstname = '".$firstname."'
    , lastname = '".$lastname."'
    , email = '".$email."'
    , telephone = '".$telephone."'
    , fax = '".$fax."'
    , ip = '".$ip."'
    , date_added = NOW()
    , date_modified = NOW()
";
```

I get the error

> Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'order customer_id =1,firstname ='kuldeep',lastname
>   ='pathak',email ='kuldeep.pat' at line 1 Error No: 1064

Comment: How did you come up with this query? Looks like an UPDATE query rather then an INSERT.

Comment: `order` is a MySQL reserved word, when used as a table or column name, wrap it in backticks

Comment: Then learn a bit about who to structure different types of SQL queries, as this looks more like an UPDATE than an INSERT

Comment: Syntax is: 
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name1, column_name2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2');

Answer (score 3):

You didnt understand how to write SQLs as it seems.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `order` (customer_id, firstname, blablabla) VALUES ('.$custormer_id.','.$firstname.','.$blablabla.')';
```

Please look at some basic tutorials about SQL.

Comment: You can do it like he does to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434851/mysql-5-1-insert-syntax-col-name-value

Comment: Hmm, i always thought that SET only works together with UPDATE.

Comment: You can do it like he says, because MySQL is forgiving; but it won't work like that with all SQL databases.... nothing like learning a way to limit yourself in the future

Comment: INSERT with values etc is the most common but the SET method works too.

Comment: Like the one posted by @Franck this won't work as of "order" is reserved by mysql.

Answer (score 1):

```
"INSERT INTO
    `order` SET customer_id = " . $customer_id . "
    , firstname = '".$firstname."'
    , lastname = '".$lastname."'
    , email = '".$email."'
    , telephone = '".$telephone."'
    , fax = '".$fax."'
    , ip = '".$ip."'
    , date_added = NOW()
    , date_modified = NOW()
";
```

Should be alright. Don´t forget to escape your data though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"INSERT INTO `Order` (customer_id, firstname, lastname, email, telephone, fax, ip, date_added, date_modified)
VALUES ($customer_id, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$telephone', '$fax', '$ip', NOW(), NOW())"
```

The right syntax is : `INSERT INTO tablename (columns) VALUES (values);`

Answer (score 0):

If you're likely to have user submitted fields in the dataset or appostrophes or anything else that could cause problems for any reason you'd want something more like

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `table` (`Name`, `Email`, `AnotherField`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s'",
mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['Name'] ),
mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['Email'] ),
mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['AnotherField'] )
);
```

This will sanitise your inputs as well

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statement to avoiding sql injection.

```
$custormer_id = "2000";
$firstname = "first name";
$etc = "some other values";
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO order(customer_id, firstname, etc) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('iss', $custormer_id, $firstname, $etc);
// first parameter is corresponding variable type of inserting values,eg i=interger, s=string
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php